# What version of Hilt is compatible with Gradle 8?

Tags: android, gradle

I get an error when I try to add Hilt dependency to a new Compose project in Android:

```
> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
  Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

It turns out that by default Android Studio creates a new project with:

- **Android Gradle Pugin: 8.1.1**
- **Gradle version: 8.0**
- **Kotlin version 1.8.0**.

So I added **Hilt version 2.44** as mentioned on the official website https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android and when I try to build and run the project. I run into the issue mentioned more above.

- My Android Studio version: **Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1**
- Gradle JDK: Android Studio default SDK Jetbrains **Runtime version 17.0.6**

*Workaround:*
For now I only find the following solution, but I wonder if this is correct or a there's better one.

```
tasks {
    withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KaptGenerateStubs::class.java).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
}

dependencies { ...
```

Comment: I think this is not about Hilt being compatible rather Java 1.8 not sitting well with Gradle 8.

Answer (score 0):

Update the java version to 19. If your sdk is java 19.

```
tasks {
    withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KaptGenerateStubs::class.java).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "19"
        }
    }
}
```

If it still doesn't work then used the hilt version I am using. I am using 2.50.